# In the time of Execution it added 10 once If i Execute again it throw below given Error

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

**Question**: write a procedure to insert record in table where `EMPNO`  is the primary key. If we insert any duplicate `EMPNO`, we show an error

> unique value constraint violated

In the place of duplicate, value 10 will be added to the `EMPNO` and insert the data into the table.

And if any other errors occur, handle the error through an exception.

Code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE check_duplicate_row IS
    PRAGMA autonomous_transaction;
    CURSOR table1_data IS
    SELECT
        empno,
        empname
    FROM
        employee_details;

    employee_record table1_data%rowtype;
BEGIN
    FOR employee_record IN table1_data LOOP
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO emp_target (
                empno,
                empname
            ) VALUES (
                employee_record.empno,
                employee_record.empname
            );

            EXIT WHEN table1_data%notfound;
            COMMIT;
        EXCEPTION
            WHEN dup_val_on_index THEN
                INSERT INTO emp_target (
                    empno,
                    empname
                )
                    SELECT
                        empno + 10,
                        empname
                    FROM
                        employee_details;

                COMMIT;
        END;
    END LOOP;
END;
/
```

> Error starting at line : 57 in command -
> BEGIN check_duplicate_row; END;
>
> Error report:
>
> ORA-00001: unique constraint (ADWHS.EMP_TARGET_PK) violated
> ORA-06512: at "ADWHS.CHECK_DUPLICATE_ROW", line 20
> ORA-06512: at "ADWHS.CHECK_DUPLICATE_ROW", line 20
> ORA-00001: unique constraint (ADWHS.EMP_TARGET_PK) violated
> ORA-06512: at "ADWHS.CHECK_DUPLICATE_ROW", line 14
> ORA-06512: at line 1
>
> 1. 00000 -  "unique constraint (%s.%s) violated"
>    Cause: An UPDATE or INSERT statement attempted to insert a duplicate key.
>    For Trusted Oracle configured in DBMS MAC mode, you may see this message if a duplicate entry exists at a different level.
>    Action: Either remove the unique restriction or do not insert the key.

Answer (score 0):

I put some changes with some names and data (fix values) but you have a few issues in the code.
Your second attempt (within Exception) to write a record with +10 empno does not have a propper pl/sql block with an exception part to handle the error. And in the first block exception does not handle possible other errors. Adopt this to your table/column names and to your actual data and see what happens when you run it first time and what when you run it again...

```sql
create or replace PROCEDURE check_duplicate_row IS
    PRAGMA autonomous_transaction;
    CURSOR table1_data IS
    SELECT
        7900 as empno,
        'SOME_NAME' as empname
    FROM
        dual;

    employee_record table1_data%rowtype;
BEGIN
    FOR employee_record IN table1_data LOOP
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO emp (
                empno,
                ename
            ) VALUES (
                employee_record.empno,
                employee_record.empname
            );

            EXIT WHEN table1_data%notfound;
            COMMIT;
        EXCEPTION
            WHEN dup_val_on_index THEN
                DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX exception raised --> Trying again with empno+10...');
                BEGIN
                    INSERT INTO emp (
                        empno,
                        ename
                    )
                        SELECT
                            7900 + 10 as empno,
                            'SOME_NAME' as empname
                        FROM
                            dual;
                    COMMIT;
                    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Succes with empno+10...');
                EXCEPTION
                    WHEN dup_val_on_index THEN
                        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX exception raised again --> second attempt failed   --> getting out ...');
                    WHEN OTHERS THEN
                        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(SQLERRM);
                END;
            WHEN OTHERS THEN
                  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(SQLERRM);
        END;
    END LOOP;
END;
```

It should be something like this:

```sql
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
Begin
    CHECK_DUPLICATE_ROW();
End;
--  R e s u l t   1st run
--  anonymous block completed
--  DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX exception raised --> Trying again with empno+10...
--  Succes with empno+10...
--  
--  R e s u l t   2nd run
--  anonymous block completed
--  DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX exception raised --> Trying again with empno+10...
--  DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX exception raised again --> second attempt failed   --> getting out ...
```

Also, the name of the procedure is missleading as it is, actually, an insert record procedure not check duplicates one. It does some exception handling of the duplicates, but basically it is an insert procedure. Regards...